# How to change the style of sorting icon in Material UI table?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make the sorting icons in material table be slightly visible even when they are hidden. Currently the opacity of the icons is 0 when not selected/visible. But I want to change it to 0.4 so that they are slightly visible and when selected the opacity will be 1 so they will be completely visible.
Since the icons are part of tableHead and I don't have access to the parent of icons I don't know how to override the styles.

Here's the code that I have tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kk7yqr8285?module=%2Fdemo.js

Answer (score 6):

You need to [override the internal styles](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/) of the `TableSortLabel` component. Specifically, if you look at the [CSS API of `TableSortLabel`](https://material-ui-next.com/api/table-sort-label/#css-api), you'll see that the `TableSortLabel` has an `icon` style.

So, first define these styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  // Fully visible for active icons
  activeSortIcon: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
  // Half visible for inactive icons
  inactiveSortIcon: {
    opacity: 0.4,
  },
});
```

Then, override the `icon` style in your `TableSortLabel` using your logic for determining whether a sort icon is active or not:

```
<TableSortLabel
  classes={{
    // Override with the active class if this is the selected column or inactive otherwise
    icon: ((orderBy === column.id) ? classes.activeSortIcon : classes.inactiveSortIcon ) }}
>
```

Your initial solution had the right styling and logic, but your inline styles were overruled by the internal styling of the `TableSortLabel` component. In general, when you want to change the internal styling of a component, you'll need to use overrides like we did here.

If you're not familiar with the concept of defining styles and applying them to components with the `classes` prop, you can learn about that [here](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/). Make sure to check out the code examples both on that page and throughout the rest of the docs.