# How could I change mui x-data-grid sorting icon and menu icon color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I see that there are `filterIcon`, `menuIcon` and `menuIconButton` properties, but I do not have any idea how to apply them.

```
<DataGrid
   rows={rows}
   columns={columns}
   rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPage}
   disableSelectionOnClick
   // should be some stuff here
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this approach. First define the styles

```
const styles = theme => ({
  activeSortIcon: {
    opacity: 1,
    color : 'blue',
  },
  inactiveSortIcon: {
    opacity: 0.4,
    color : 'green',
  },
});
```

Then use these styles in DataGrid component according to your logic how to use it

```
<DataGrid
   rows={rows}
   columns={columns}
   rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPage}
   disableSelectionOnClick
   classes={{
   icon: ((orderBy === column.id) ? classes.activeSortIcon : 
   classes.inactiveSortIcon ) 
   }}
   // should be some stuff here
/>
```

You can add different icons in styles instead of colors using this approach. Hope this approach might be helpful. Please let me know if this worked.

Reference : [How to change the style of sorting icon in Material UI table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167728/how-to-change-the-style-of-sorting-icon-in-material-ui-table)

Comment: I just needed this stuff with the class, then I just passed what I needed in mu case sortIcon, menuIconButton and iconSeparator

Comment: `classes={{
            sortIcon: classes.sortIcon,
            menuIconButton: classes.menuIcon,
            iconSeparator: classes.iconSeparator,
          }}`

Comment: Great !!. Good to know , the proposed solution worked

Answer (score 2):

For those still interested in styling the MUI-data grid icons, you can also utilize a styled component vs. using classes.

```
const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)((theme) => ({
"& .MuiDataGrid-sortIcon": {
opacity: 1,
color: "white",
},
"& .MuiDataGrid-menuIconButton": {
opacity: 1,
color: "white"
},
}));
```

Now you return your styled component since we've declared the styles accordingly:

```
<StyledDataGrid
rows={x}
columns={columnDef}
autoHeight
...more stuff if you want...
/>
```

There you go! You don't need to declare classes or anything.
Also, the styled component allows you to style everything in the data grid with the proper referencing (MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders, MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle, Mui-selected, etc.)

Feel free to take a look at this explanation on MUI styled components:
https://mui.com/system/styled/